# If $Y-f(A)$ is a subset of $f(X-A)$ then $f$ is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X → Y$ a function

Also, $A \subset X $

I did the following

\begin{align*}
&\text{Let }x \in A \\
\Rightarrow \quad & x \not \in X-A \\
\Rightarrow \quad & f(x) \not \in  f(X-A) \\
\Rightarrow \quad & f(x) \not \in Y-f(A) \\
\Rightarrow \quad & f(x) \in f(A) \subset Y\\
\Rightarrow \quad & f(x) \in Y \\
\Rightarrow \quad & f(x) \subset Y \\
\end{align*}

Now, I need to prove that $Y \subset f(x)$. But I cant do it because I need that f be injective

Comment: Please give full details of your question.  What are the domain and codomain of $f$?  I'm guessing $f:X\to Y$, but you should not make readers guess about important details.

Comment: More importantly, is the hypothesis that $Y-f(A)\subseteq f(X-A)$ for some specified set $A$?  Or for some (unspecified) $A$?  Or for all $A$?

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**.  Let $f:X\to Y$.  Suppose that there exists $A\subseteq X$ with the property that
$$Y-f(A)\subseteq f(X-A)\ .$$
Then $f$ is onto.

**Partial proof**, see if you can finish it.  Let $y\in Y$.  We have to show that $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ in $X$.

Case 1, $y\in f(A)$.  Then $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ in ....

Case 2, $y\not\in f(A)$.  Then $y\in f(\cdots)$ and therefore $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ in ....